# PHP Uploading large file from client side using Google Drive API

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

I have problem with uploading large file (movie file approx 1gb) from my admin panel (using Laravel) to Google drive by using Google drive API, I have changed php.ini upload max file and post max size to >1gb, then the error show about memory limit. So if I want to upload 1gb file the memory limit should be > 1gb?